# Exit after trap fires

Tags: bash, shell-trap

Take this script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

fd ()
{
  echo Hello world
  exit
}

trap fd EXIT INT

for g in {1..5}
do
  echo foo
  sleep 1
done
```

I would like `fd` to fire once, either from Control-C or if the script exits normally. However if you hit Control-C it will run twice. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do cascading traps. `exit 127` will run the `EXIT` trap and set the exit code to 127, so you can say

```
#!/bin/sh

fd () {
  echo Hello world
  # No explicit exit here!
}

trap fd EXIT
trap 'exit 127' INT
```

I remember learning this from other people's scripts after struggling with various workarounds to your problem for several years. After that, I have noticed that some tutorials do explain this technique. But it is not documented clearly in e.g. the Bash manual page IMHO. (Or it wasn't when I needed it. Maybe some things don't change in 15 years ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [**pst’s comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275224/exit-after-trap-fires#comment19818269_14275224)

```sh
fd ()
{
  echo Hello world
  trap - EXIT INT
  exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about in redefining trap default?

```
#!/bin/sh

fd () {
   echo Hello world
   trap - EXIT
   exit 127
}

trap fd INT EXIT
```